# Action bar menu item navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I am using a navigation drawer menu with fragments. Which is the simplest way to display only when one of this fragments is selected in the `ListView` of the `Navigation Drawer` an `ActionBar` menu item icon and remove when other fragment is selected. Is there some simple example? I am using `appcompat`. Thank you so much.

On my fragment:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

and:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.logout).setVisible(true);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

And on my activity:

```
@Override
            public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
                boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
                menu.findItem(R.id.logout).setVisible(false);//(!drawerOpen);
                return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
            }
```

My menu main.xml:

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/navbar_salir"
        yourapp:showAsAction="always"
       />
</menu>
```

Comment: What you are saying is that you want different `MenuItems` for different `Fragments`? You just have to call `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in the `Fragment` and from then on you can use the `Fragment` callbacks for menus. They are called the same as in the `Activity`.

Comment: I have edited my question with the code, somebody can help me please